# why this sequence of functions does not uniformly converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that the sequence:
$$h_n(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) \mbox{ if } x=0\mbox{ or }x\notin\mathbb{Q}\\
x(b+\frac{1}{n})(1+\frac{1}{n})\mbox{ if } x\in\mathbb{Q}.
\end{cases}$$

Does not uniformly converges at any bounded interval.

This excercise was taken from the book ``Mathemathical Analysis'' of Tom Apostol.

Answer (score 1):

I can't add comment yet but I think you can use the Uniform convergence theorem to prove this. Assume it is convergent then the limit function would be continuos, which is not true as it is discontinuous at every rational x

Edit:Yes the functions are not continuous. I'm wrong

Comment: I can't see how to use this theorem because not all he functions in the sequence are continous... isn't it?

Comment: Edit:Yes the functions are not continuous. I'm wrong